# What the result of multipling the eigenvalues by the eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Multiplying the eigenvalues by the eigenvectors. Does this give any meaningful result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the definition of an eigenvector is:

> Suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation on some vector space and $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector in that space. Then $\mathbf{v}$ is an **eigenvector** of $T$ if and only if $\mathbf{v}$ is not the zero vector, and there is some scalar $\lambda$ such that
>
> $$T(\mathbf{v}) = \lambda \mathbf{v}.$$
>
> If $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector, then $\lambda$ is its **eigenvalue**.

So if you have an eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, the significance of the product $\lambda \mathbf{v}$ is that it's the same as $T(\mathbf{v})$.